# Cannot open solution file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed the Visual Studio Code on Windows. When I try to open a solution file in VS Code it opens the solution file, instead of opening all projects in solution. Is there a way to open existing project solutions in VS Code?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

When you open a folder in VSCode, it will automatically scan the folder for typical project artifacts like project.json or solution files. From the status bar in the lower left side you can switch between solutions and projects.

Comment: As of right now (version 0.10.1) Code is opening solutions for me just fine! I opened the folder like you said, and poof 

Comment: The lower left has git controls?

Comment: this doesn't work in Linux, I'm using version 1.12.1

Comment: Lots of tools in VS Code don't work just from opening the folder. For example, "Find All References" only works for the current file.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the status bar where you can change the view? I am not able to find it

Comment: @DM it's likely to the right of the Omniserver "flame" icon at the bottom left of the screen. If you don't see it, you may need to ctrl+shift+p > restart Omniserver.

Comment: VS Code 1.86.0 does not scan and open solution

Answer (score 81):

Use `vscode-solution-explorer` extension:

> This extension adds a Visual Studio Solution File explorer panel in Visual Studio Code. Now you can navigate into your solution following the original Visual Studio structure.

https://github.com/fernandoescolar/vscode-solution-explorer

[image]

Thanks [@fernandoescolar](https://github.com/fernandoescolar)

Comment: please, create a issue in https://github.com/fernandoescolar/vscode-solution-explorer/issues

Comment: This is not a full solution for running Visual Studio solutions in VS Code though, right? I can't simply open a solution and click a button to compile a build configuration etc., as far as I can tell.

Comment: I cannot add any references with this extension.

Answer (score 42):

VSCode is a code editor, not a full IDE. Think of VSCode as a notepad on steroids with IntelliSense code completion, richer semantic code understanding of multiple languages, code refactoring, including navigation, keyboard support with customizable bindings, syntax highlighting, bracket matching, auto indentation, and snippets.

It's not meant to replace Visual Studio, but making "Visual Studio" part of the name in VSCode will of course confuse some people at first.

Answer (score 10):

But you can open the folder with the .SLN in to edit the code in the project, which will detect the .SLN to select the library that provides Intellisense.

Answer (score 3):

You have to open separate instances of VSCode in the directory where the solution is that you want to edit code under.  VSCode doesn't use a hierarchical reference system to scope each source file to the appropriate solution/project.  It's just not that mature/capable of that.

Answer (score 1):

Solution files are now officially supported via the [C# Dev Kit extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csdevkit).

From the extension description:

> C# Dev Kit helps you manage your code with a solution explorer and test your code with integrated unit test discovery and execution, elevating your C# development experience wherever you like to develop (Windows, macOS, Linux, and even in a Codespace).

[Project management documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/project-management) for VS Code, detailing the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score -2):

In the VSCode Marketplace look up and install vscode-solution-explorer

Answer (score -2):

vscode-solution-explorer
This is the extension you are looking for

Comment: George Paoli already posted this answer with a lot more detail way back in February, 2018 (five and a half years ago). Please don't repeat answers.