# How to open project VS 2015 with VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio

I have developed a project (AngularJS, NodeJS, ExpressJS) with Visual Studio 2015 (.sln) in Windows, and want to know how I can open it with Visual Studio Code in iOS.

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48825278/2076784

Answer (score 1):

**Visual Studio Code** is meant to be a powerful editor and not a full IDE. So, it isn't designed to work with project files *(**.sln** or **.csproj**)*.

If you want to use your project created in Windows, then create a .NET Core application. See, more information on the [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/core).

Also, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985273/6290553) explanation by [Benjamin Pasero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851043/benjamin-pasero).