# How do I use Visual Studio Code to build, debug and run existing C++ solution (.sln) from Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, g++, c++17

I have an existing C++ solution which I have been building and running using Visual Studio 2019. I would like to build and run the application on Ubuntu using g++ and Visual Studio Code. What is the best way of achieving this? Most of the samples provided are building single .cpp file but my application consists of many .cpp files built into one application executable.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux
[How do I set up Visual Studio Code to compile C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-visual-studio-code-to-compile-c-code)

I have installed the https://github.com/fernandoescolar/vscode-solution-explorer extension but that only enables me to browse the C++ solution. How to build the solution and being able to debug and run the C++ application?

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: Possibly relevant/helpful/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29972270/10871073?

Comment: use MSBuild to build a `.proj` file

Comment: @rioV8 can you provide more details? I have installed dotnet sdk but I don't find msbuild command installed with it.

Comment: @AdrianMole ok, I have installed the extension but that only enables me to browse the C++ solution. How to build the solution and being able to debug and run the C++ application?

Comment: which C++ compiler do you want to use? MSBuild is just Like CMake and Make a build tool, if you install VS Community Edition you get a C++ compiler and build tool, MSBuild uses .proj files to specify what needs to be done

Comment: VS Code with g++ on Ubuntu. Not Windows!

Comment: I hope you find this answer helpful: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/75110946/20707965**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CMake` and generate `CMakeLists.txt` from `.sln` and included `.vcxproj` using https://github.com/pavelliavonau/cmakeconverter
`cmake-converter -s MyProject.sln`

Answer (score 0):

In one of the sections, I provide information on how to build solution files in **Visual Studio Code** in Windows (I believe it is similar for other systems): **https://stackoverflow.com/a/75110946/20707965**